# Paypal Smart Buttons - Expires Field (yy vs yyyy)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I just installed Paypal Smart Buttons on my website and to my surprise the *Expires* field does not get auto filled since it's MM/YY rather than MM/YYYY. I looked through the documentation and found nothing in regards how to change this. Has anyone managed to get around this issue?

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on this and found that if the attribute `autocomplete="cc-exp-year"` were set on the form field per Chrome's spec, it might make this field auto-complete automatically. I sent this tip PayPal's way for them to investigate as a potential bug/improvement since it'll be best to make this work for everyone.

(There might be a way to make just your browser recognize the field, but that won't help customers)

Comment: Yup, I did some digging as well and came to the same conclusion. If you've previously saved your card details in MM/YY format it works, but that doesn't seem to be the standard. (I have multiple cards, never ran into this issue before). Thanks for checking, extra eyes always helps :)